# Style bullet-list with arrows

Tags: css, list

I have created an arrow that I would like to attach to a list instead of the round bullet points. I have tried to use the :after but haven't succeeded yet, have to confess that I'm very new to pseudo-elements...

Here's what I got so far:

```css
#arrow {
    border-right:2px solid black;
    border-bottom:2px solid black;
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    margin-top:40px;
}



ul li {
 padding-bottom: 10px;
}

ul li:before{
   border-right:5px solid black;
   border-bottom:5px solid black;
   width:10px;
   height:10px;
   transform: rotate(-45deg);
   margin-top:40px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Arrow below -->
<div id="arrow"></div>


<!-- Want to place arrow where bullet points are  -->
<ul>
  <li>Item #1</li>
  <li>Item #2</li>
  <li>Item #3</li>
  <li>Item #4</li>
  <li>Item #5</li>
</ul>
```

Anyone who got any ideas?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use `content: ''` with pseudo elements (`:before` or `:after`). And use `list-style: none` for `ul` to remove the bullets. Like:

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

ul li:before{
   content: '';
   position: absolute;
   border-right:2px solid black;
   border-bottom:2px solid black;
   width:10px;
   height:10px;
   top: calc(50% - 4px);
   left: -20px;
   transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(-45deg);
}
```

Have a look at the snippet below:

```css
#arrow {
    border-right:2px solid black;
    border-bottom:2px solid black;
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    margin-top:40px;
}



ul li {
  position: relative;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

ul li:before{
   content: '';
   position: absolute;
   border-right:2px solid black;
   border-bottom:2px solid black;
   width:10px;
   height:10px;
   top: calc(50% - 4px);
   left: -20px;
   transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<!-- Want to place arrow where bullet points are  -->
<ul>
  <li>Item #1</li>
  <li>Item #2</li>
  <li>Item #3</li>
  <li>Item #4</li>
  <li>Item #5</li>
</ul>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Helped! Thanx, I now understand why It didn't work my way  :)

Comment: Its my pleasure.

Comment: Check my answer below for a solution without position absolute/relative.

Answer (score 18):

Not directly answering the question asked, but hopefully useful to some people who found this question from a search like I did!

Using roughly the same idea as other answers, but with a simpler `::before` pseudo-element, you can use any unicode arrow character for your bullet rather than messing about with borders on divs:

```css
ul {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
}

li::before {
  content: '▶';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
```

Here is a list of unicode arrows, so you can find something that you like: http://xahlee.info/comp/unicode_arrows.html

Comment: Using `li::before` with borders also increases the content height (visible as space between `li` items). Your method avoids any changes, allowing for greater control.

Answer (score 5):

A more modern (2021) approach would be:

Note: The centering and the colors are optional.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none
}

li {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 20px auto;
  justify-content: start;
  align-items: center;
}

li::before {
  content: ">";
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #999;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

just add content in before and display inline-block

```css
#arrow {
    border-right:2px solid black;
    border-bottom:2px solid black;
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    margin-top:40px;
}

ul li {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    list-style:none;
}

ul li:before {
    border-right: 2px solid black;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a minor variation on Jamie Humphries' Answer that I was happy with.  The example below uses styling with SASS (.scss) rather than CSS.  I really enjoy the fact that the bullets get their own styling apart from the line items.

```
<ul class="myclass">
  <li><a href="myhref">Item One</a></li>
  <li><a href="myhref">Item Two</a></li>
  <li><a href="myhref">Item Three</a></li>
</ul

ul.myclass {
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: 30px;

    li::before {
        content: '▶';
        color: #8090c0;
    }

    li {
        margin-bottom: 12px;

        a {
            padding-left: 10px;
            font-size: 1.4em;
            color: #0000e0;
        }
    }
}
```